# Facebook Connect Question

Tags: php, facebook

Lets say I do the following line of code to display a login button on my site:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();


<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
      <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
</a>
```

If a user logs in through this method, by default which permissions will we have? Is there a way to specify which permissions you want to have? (Such as getting his birthday, list of friends, gender, photo url, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you add permissions:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    "scope" => "read_stream,email"
));
```

Comment: thanks!by the way,do you know if there's any way to show the 'invite friends' box using the php api,or do i need to use the javascript for that?